TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" (but function is public)
If possible please some help !
I create a contract in Solidity. Because its size is too big i try a way to move some functions to a     second contract to free some space.So i have this :
The main contract
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "./EscrowHandler.sol";
import "./SharedStructs.sol";    

the library SharedStructs.sol
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library SharedStructs {
    enum AssetType { MyCoin }
    enum PaymentMethod { Ether, USDT }

    struct Order {
    uint256 orderID;
    address buyer;
    address payable owner;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 fulfilledAmount;
    AssetType assetType;
    PaymentMethod priceCurrency;
}
    
}    

and the escrow handler (some other functions maybe will go here too)
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "./SharedStructs.sol";
import "./i_MyCoin.sol";
contract EscrowHandler {
    // State variables and mappings related to escrows
    mapping(address => mapping(SharedStructs.AssetType => uint256)) assetBalances;
    mapping(address => mapping(SharedStructs.PaymentMethod => uint256)) escrowBalances;
    // Buy orders separate queues for Ether and USDT
    SharedStructs.Order[] buyOrdersEther;
    SharedStructs.Order[] buyOrdersUSDT;
    // Sell orders separate queues for Ether and USDT
    SharedStructs.Order[] sellOrdersEther;
    SharedStructs.Order[] sellOrdersUSDT;    
    

so on escrow handler i have this function

    function removeOrder(SharedStructs.Order[] storage orders, uint index) internal {
    require(index < orders.length, "Index out of bounds");

    for (uint i = index; i < orders.length - 1; i++) {
        orders[i] = orders[i + 1];
    }
    orders.pop();
}    

so i want to call it also from other contracts for example from myCoin.sol .
Because is internal , i create a public function which will call it :

    function removeOrderExternal(SharedStructs.Order[] storage orders, uint index) public {
    removeOrder(orders, index);
}    

normally should edit the storage orders.So i set "storage orders" but then i receive error
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in function, but "storage" was given.   


      --> contracts/EscrowHandler.sol:68:30:
   |
68 | function removeOrderExternal(SharedStructs.Order[] storage orders, uint index) public {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   

and of course if i set it to memory like this ,

    function removeOrderExternal(SharedStructs.Order[] memory orders, uint index) public {
    removeOrder(orders, index);
}    

i receive this :
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct  SharedStructs.Order[] memory to struct SharedStructs.Order[] storage pointer requested.  

     --> contracts/EscrowHandler.sol:69:17:
   |
69 |     removeOrder(orders, index);
   |                 ^^^^^^    
 

because the orders are in storage and not in memory.
So is it possible somehow with public function to edit the storage arrays ? I can not find solution to  this. I think solidity not allowing public function to edit storage. But then how i should do it ?
